# Cannot import Optuna after installing Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, optuna

Optuna is clashing with some other module and can't import - I think pytorch is to blame.

The error when importing optuna is:

```
TypeError: dataclass_transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'field_specifiers'
```

It was working fine until I installed pytorch, but I can't find any reason why they would clash, I've updated all packages to the latest version etc.

Annoyingly pytorch also seems to have broken matplotlib, I've tried the 'truetype' version fix, but no luck

Full verbose error below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-44e13f4113b4> in <module>
     89 from IPython.display import clear_output
     90 
---> 91 import optuna

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from optuna import integration
      4 from optuna import logging
----> 5 from optuna import multi_objective
      6 from optuna import pruners
      7 from optuna import samplers

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\multi_objective\__init__.py in <module>
      1 from optuna._imports import _LazyImport
----> 2 from optuna.multi_objective import samplers
      3 from optuna.multi_objective import study
      4 from optuna.multi_objective import trial
      5 from optuna.multi_objective.study import create_study

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\multi_objective\samplers\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from optuna.multi_objective.samplers._adapter import _MultiObjectiveSamplerAdapter
      2 from optuna.multi_objective.samplers._base import BaseMultiObjectiveSampler
      3 from optuna.multi_objective.samplers._motpe import MOTPEMultiObjectiveSampler
      4 from optuna.multi_objective.samplers._nsga2 import NSGAIIMultiObjectiveSampler
      5 from optuna.multi_objective.samplers._random import RandomMultiObjectiveSampler

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\multi_objective\samplers\_adapter.py in <module>
      4 from optuna import multi_objective
      5 from optuna.distributions import BaseDistribution
----> 6 from optuna.samplers import BaseSampler
      7 from optuna.study import Study
      8 from optuna.trial import FrozenTrial

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\samplers\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from optuna.samplers import nsgaii
      2 from optuna.samplers._base import BaseSampler
      3 from optuna.samplers._brute_force import BruteForceSampler
      4 from optuna.samplers._cmaes import CmaEsSampler
      5 from optuna.samplers._grid import GridSampler

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\samplers\nsgaii\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from optuna.samplers.nsgaii._crossovers._base import BaseCrossover
      2 from optuna.samplers.nsgaii._crossovers._blxalpha import BLXAlphaCrossover
      3 from optuna.samplers.nsgaii._crossovers._sbx import SBXCrossover
      4 from optuna.samplers.nsgaii._crossovers._spx import SPXCrossover
      5 from optuna.samplers.nsgaii._crossovers._undx import UNDXCrossover

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\samplers\nsgaii\_crossovers\_base.py in <module>
      3 import numpy as np
      4 
----> 5 from optuna.study import Study
      6 
      7 

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\__init__.py in <module>
      2 from optuna.study._study_direction import StudyDirection
      3 from optuna.study._study_summary import StudySummary
----> 4 from optuna.study.study import copy_study
      5 from optuna.study.study import create_study
      6 from optuna.study.study import delete_study

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\study\study.py in <module>
     24 from optuna import pruners
     25 from optuna import samplers
---> 26 from optuna import storages
     27 from optuna import trial as trial_module
     28 from optuna._convert_positional_args import convert_positional_args

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\storages\__init__.py in <module>
      3 from optuna._callbacks import RetryFailedTrialCallback
      4 from optuna.storages._base import BaseStorage
----> 5 from optuna.storages._cached_storage import _CachedStorage
      6 from optuna.storages._heartbeat import fail_stale_trials
      7 from optuna.storages._in_memory import InMemoryStorage

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\storages\_cached_storage.py in <module>
     17 from optuna.storages import BaseStorage
     18 from optuna.storages._heartbeat import BaseHeartbeat
---> 19 from optuna.storages._rdb.storage import RDBStorage
     20 from optuna.study._frozen import FrozenStudy
     21 from optuna.study._study_direction import StudyDirection

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\storages\_rdb\storage.py in <module>
     28 from optuna.storages._base import DEFAULT_STUDY_NAME_PREFIX
     29 from optuna.storages._heartbeat import BaseHeartbeat
---> 30 from optuna.storages._rdb.models import TrialValueModel
     31 from optuna.study._frozen import FrozenStudy
     32 from optuna.study._study_direction import StudyDirection

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\optuna\storages\_rdb\models.py in <module>
     17 from sqlalchemy import func
     18 from sqlalchemy import Integer
---> 19 from sqlalchemy import orm
     20 from sqlalchemy import String
     21 from sqlalchemy import Text

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\__init__.py in <module>
     55 from .context import FromStatement as FromStatement
     56 from .context import QueryContext as QueryContext
---> 57 from .decl_api import add_mapped_attribute as add_mapped_attribute
     58 from .decl_api import as_declarative as as_declarative
     59 from .decl_api import declarative_base as declarative_base

~\.conda\envs\Alex_env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py in <module>
    160         composite,
    161         synonym,
--> 162         deferred,
    163     ),
    164 )
```

It worked previously, now I get the error above

Comment: "it previously worked" . . . so what did you change ? show the code or change that creates the error. [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry :) it worked, then I installed pytorch, now I can't import optuna

Comment: Ok I fixed this - f the haters.
I had to uninstall pytorch, and reinstall the last version before 2.0, then reinstall optuna using pip. The command I used for pytorch etc was:
conda install pytorch==1.13.1 torchvision==0.14.1 torchaudio==0.13.1 pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia